# How to properly launch an Activity stack from Android Notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

[image]

**The setup:**

- I have 9 Fragments placed inside MainActivity.
- There is a seperate background service which has a notification active all the time while it's alive. (Playing audio)
- After application is closed with the home button, touching the notification opens the application.
- When a certain object is selected inside a fragment (audio track), a new Activity is loaded (NowplayingActivity)

**What I need:**

- I want everything the same, except, I want the system to open MainActivity first, than, NowplayingActivity when notification is touched.

**What I tried:**

- *I couldn't make `TaskStackBuilder` work correctly.(Maybe it is not for this kind of stuff) MainActivity is never shown (but the NowplayingActivity) even though I have parentActivity defined in manifest file.

  - I tried passing a logical command in Intent's extras ("when you are created, open NowplayingActivity"). This works. But as `onNewIntent` is called before Fragments on the MainActivity created completely, fragments do not receive hints for visibility changes and also they are not paused... I can delay the launch of the other Activity while inside `onNewIntent`, but this is ugly.

What can I try? What am I missing here?

**update** (added non-working code for the TaskStackBuilder method)
*

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:label="MMM"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
...
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"/>
```

.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NowplayingActivity.class);          
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);  
stackBuilder.addParentStack(NowplayingActivity.class); 
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

//PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: could you provide the code where you build TaskStackBuilder?

Comment: @KostasMatrix I updated the question with the non-working code.